# calculating the gcd and lcm of 5 numbers

Tags: java, loops, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

how can i calculate the GCD and LCM of 5 numbers using a loop that i should create??
    this is what i started doing but i think i started in wrong way from the beginning can anyone help

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int nbr1=input.nextInt();
    int nbr2=input.nextInt();
    int nbr3=input.nextInt();
    int nbr4=input.nextInt();
    int nbr5=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=nbr1;(i%nbr2==0 || i%nbr3==0 ||i%nbr3||i%nbr4==0 || i%nbr5==0 ;i++)
    {       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should add input.nextLine() in between every nextInt().

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find GCF, LCM on a set of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201860/how-to-find-gcf-lcm-on-a-set-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `arrayOfInts` in java for calculating GCD and LCM of multiple numbers and possibly this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689529/lcm-of-all-the-numbers-in-an-array-in-java) can guide you better.